# Loading OPeNDAP served netcdf file using ncdf4 in R under Windows

Tags: r, netcdf, opendap

I have a script that downloads NetCDF data from an OPeNDAP server using the package `ncdf4`. The script works on my Mac laptop but fails on my Windows 7 desktop. On both machines, I am using the latest available version of `R` and `ncdf4` (on Windows, it's R3.2.2 with `ncdf4_1_9` installed from the latest available zip file; on the Mac, it is `ncdf4_1.13` installed from source).

It works fine for opening locally stored NetCDF files, but when I try to access a NetCDF file from an OPeNDAP server (on Windows only), I get the error

> Error in R_nc4_open: Invalid argument

I seem to be getting this error regardless of which opendap-served netcdf file I try to open. The one I actually need to access is currently not publicly available (served only internally), but I get the same message, for instance, when I try:

```
nc <- nc_open("http://measures.gsfc.nasa.gov/opendap/test/GOZ-Merged-MLP_H2O_ev1-01_1992.nc4")
```

or:

```
nc_open("http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/ncep.marine/cldc.mean.nc")
```

Any tips? Escaping the slashes in the URL doesn't work. I'm hoping I won't need to install ncdf4 from source under Windows.

Comment: I am not sure whether `ncdf4` under Windows has OPeNDAP capability.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, and to improve the format of the question.

Comment: Can you run `nc-config --has-dap` on a command prompt/terminal? Make sure it says "yes" for OPeNDAP support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s now a version of the ncdf4 library on github that correctly handles OPeNDAP-served files:

```
devtools::install_github(‘mdsumner/ncdf4’)
```